# Using await in Azure Cloud Service Run Override

Tags: .net, azure, async-await

Are there any gotchas with using using `await` in Azure Cloud Service Run Override?

I added an `await` call to one function call and started getting very odd behaviour, with subsequent method calls returning apparently instantly (although they should have taken a few seconds) and VS.NET 2012 locking up and requiring a complete restart.

At present the only thought I have is that after the `await` call the `Run` method is executing on a different thread and perhaps there is a requirement in Azure that this `Run` override always runs on a fixed thread?

But if this is the case is there a way to ensure the `await` calls always synchronize back to this thread?

Or could something else be at play?

Comment: I have no idea if this is your problem, but if you're using `async`-`await` with VS 2010, it means you're using the async CTP, which is not stable. You should instead use VS 2012, if you can.

Comment: Actually, I am using VS.NET 2012, not sure why I wrote 2010. Thanks though, and I think Stephen's answer has nailed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the [documentation for `Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.run.ASPX), your method should not return; if it does, the Azure runtime interprets that as an error and will restart your role.

`await` causes its method to return when it waits for an operation. If that isn't clear, then I have an [`async` intro on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that you may find helpful.

So, the `Run` method cannot be `async`.

I usually install an `async`-compatible "main loop" in my `Run` method and then run an infinite loop inside that. My [AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/) has a "main loop" type called `AsyncContext`, which can be used like this:

```
public override void Run()
{
  try
  {
    AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
    {
      // Can use await safely in here.
      while (true)
        ;
    });
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // log
    throw;
  }
}
```

The drawback to this approach is that it only effectively uses a single thread in the role instance. I just design mine to scale out and only use the single-core sizes; it's easier than using the multi-core sizes and adding code to support multiple `async` threads.

Comment: Could you please clarify: when you are saying "it only effectively uses a single thread", does it mean that even if I want to spawn some threads inside (with `Parallel.ForEach`, for instance), I will still not be able to do that? And if I do `await Task.WhenAll(myTasks)`, I am guaranteed they will in fact be executed synchronously one after the other?

Comment: @MichaelSagalovich: No, and sort-of-yes. If you use `Parallel`, then you'll be using multiple threads just like you would normally. If you use plain `async`/`await` (and don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)`), then all the code in your asynchronous methods will be serialized. This is different than *synchronous* - the code will still be asynchronous, just serialized. Just like it was running on a UI thread.

Comment: I see... Effectively, though, will tasks in `WhenAll` execute one by one, instead of running in parallel? I know that `WhenAll` would not guarantee parallel execution anyway, but with `AsyncContext` it is definite that they will not be parallel, right?

Comment: @MichaelSagalovich: They'll run concurrently.

Comment: I am probably being a bit slow, but still. By concurrently, do you mean one thread running all tasks, switching between them? I.e., while one flow is waiting for I/O to complete (the core `await`), another flow is reusing the same thread to perform its operations (before or after the core `await`)?

Comment: @MichaelSagalovich: Yes, exactly.